# How to create a static class "property" object?

Tags: python, oop

First off I apologize if my terminology is way off and this is a basic question that has been answered a million times! I am trying to figure this out without knowing what it is called, so my searches have not been turning anything useful up...

I often find myself assigning certain "properties" to class instances in python which I will want to modify and reference later. A good example would be the "status" of an instance like in the following code:

```
class Example:
    def __init__():
        self.status = "NORMAL"

a = Example()
print(a.status)
a.status = "CANCELLED"
print(a.status)
```

While this certainly works it requires that the property is a string, which is not very maintainable and is quite prone to error. Is there some way of assigning an object to the class which can be passed to an attribute? For example (and I know this does not work):

```
class ExampleWithProperty:
    NORMAL
    CANCELLED

    def __init__()
        self.status = self.NORMAL

b = Example()
print(b.status)
# would expect: ExampleWithProperty.NORMAL or b.NORMAL
b.status = b.CANCELLED
print(b.status)
# would expect: ExampleWithProperty.CANCELLED or b.CANCELLED
```

I believe I've seen a similar functionality in other languages but I wasn't able to think of how to do this in python!

Comment: @martineau Why the edit? This seems pretty python-specific...

Comment: Spencer: Because it's not unnecessary and redundant. See the FAQ [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for Enums

```
>>> from enum import Enum
>>> class Color(Enum):
...     RED = 1
...     GREEN = 2
...     BLUE = 3
...
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html

Edit:

```py
from enum import Enum
class Status(Enum):
    NORMAL = 1
    CHANGED = 2

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.status = Status.NORMAL


instance = MyClass()
instance.status = Status.CHANGED
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that this is the same technique stdlib modules use, e.g. `re.MULTILINE` is an attriubute of `class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag)`

Comment: Hmm seems like the right idea but I'm having a hard time adding an Enum (grammer?) to an existing class. I see from the docs how to make a new class from an Enum, but what if I already have a class that I want to add to? Could you try modifying my example code with this functionality?

Comment: @Spencer I have edited the answer to include an example for what you want

Comment: I built upon this slightly and posted my own answer to match my original question better. If you have a minute I would appreciate a review of what I came up with to make sure it is all kosher! If you want I can remove that answer and just edit yours.

Answer (score 0):

To add to sergenp's helpful answer, this is how I would add an Enum to an existing class in a visually "cleaner" way which will be easier to reference from outside the class:

```
class Example():
    class StatusOptions(Enum):
        NORMAL = 0
        CANCELLED = 1

    def __init__(self):
        self.NORMAL = self.StatusOptions.NORMAL
        self.CANCELLED = self.StatusOptions.CANCELLED

        self.status = self.StatusOptions(self.NORMAL)

a = Example()
print(a.status)
a.status = a.CANCELLED
print(a.status)

print(a.status == a.CANCELLED)
```

Comment: Why did you make them instance attributes? I mean shouldn't they be class attributes?